# Mercurial merge / remove a feature branch

Tags: mercurial, branching-and-merging

I am trying to work out how to use the Branch-per-feature approach in mercurial but having created a branch to work in, and merged it back to default, am unable to push my changes back up to my master repository. What is best to do?

[image: screenshot of TortoiseHg with a branch]

I created a branch "Gauge customisation", did some work in that branch and then merged it back into the default. Carried on with a few more changes in default and now I want to commit this back to my master repository. But when I try I get:

> abort: push creates new remote branches: Gauge customisation!
>   hint: use 'hg push --new-branch' to create new remote branches

I didn't think the branching would show up in the master repo and that by merging it locally I could somehow work in the branch (or potentially branches) and then when I've tested everything, push it up to the master repo.

Should the Gauge customisation branch still show up? Really I thought I'd only see default at this stage? But is that me not understanding the tools properly? Should I be creating the remote branch?
Ideally I'd like to be able to open a branch per feature and have 3 or 4 such branches running at any one time (it's the way my company works) so I'd like to get a solid grasp of things now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically you could just commit the new branch to the master repo using `--new-branch`. As displayed in your screenshot, there is not really a new branch with a head from a topological view, but from a namespace view, i.e. when `hg` aborts your push, it just wants your explicit acknowledgement to add a new branch (name) to the remote repo.

However, for tasks like your's -- temporary feature branches -- a more common workflow is to not use named branches but anonymous/bookmarked branches or separate clones. Named branches usually are used for long-living branches like *stable*, *legacy*, and so on. If you create an anonymous/bookmarked branch and merge it back when its feature is finished, `hg` won't complain when pushing.

An often recommended reading in that context is [*A Guide to Branching in Mercurial*](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/).

Comment: My concern is that I don't want to pollute the master repo with any branches I create locally and I've heard it's a "good practice" to use the branch-per-feature approach to isolate discrete units of work that might want to be integrated separately. How that's done I'm entirely open to ideas on. 
I take on board your distinction between __temporary feature branches__ (which **is exactly** what I'm aiming at here) and __long lived branches__

The Guide to Branching looks like what I need to read next. Many thanks

Comment: In your example, the bookmarked temporary feature branch approach could have been used like this: 1) bookmark rev 44 as *main* (or master, ..), 2) bookmark rev 44 as *gauge*, 3) make and commit gauge changes, 4) update to *main*, and 5) merge *gauge* into *main*. But, personally I prefer to just work and commit and bookmark and branch when necessary. In you example this would have resulted in no branching at all since the mainline and feature work happened sequentially. You should choose your preferred way after reading the linked blog post.

Comment: This is exactly the right answer -- don't use named branches per-feature unless you want them recorded permanently in the history.  After reading "A Guide to Branching in Mercurial" read this: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StandardBranching

Answer (score 4):

Merging two branches does not get rid of either of them. You will need to close your feature branch manually by switching to it and doing:

```
hg commit --close-branch -m 'Closing branch'
```

Comment: I tried running the command and the Workbench updated to show a horizontal bar instead of the normal round icon (for the branch), but I am still unable to commit to my master repo. The returned message is as above: push creates new remote branches...

Comment: Then I shall ask the following (since it's not clearly stated in your question): have you made a push with your feature branch to your external repository before? Because if not, it is perfectly expectable that the remote repo recognizes you `hg push` as creating new branch. You should then do as suggested and add `--new branch` param to it, pushing the (now probably closed) branch to the remote repostory.

Comment: no, I didn't make any attempt to push the feature branch to the master repo. My intention with it was to create a space in which to experiment with the notion of branch-per-feature [link]http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Workflows#Feature_separation_through_named_branches[/link] and to isolate that chunk of development work from the default branch, so that I could discard it if it turned out to be a waste of time, or merge it back to default when I was happy it was done. Taking that a bit further I'd like to be able to work on multiple feature branches at once independantly

Comment: Just use --new-branch to push the closed branch to the server. The branch name will let you see where the changesets came from later.